# Is it possible to detect only one event between onkeyup and onpaste?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events

There is one `<input>` element. I added handler that is Vue directive to listen to keyup and paste event like `@keyup and @paste`.
I wanted only `onPaste` event detection when I pasted something. But it was detected both of them. Is it possible to detect only paste event? and How to?

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" @keyup="keyup" @paste="onPaste">
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  methods: {
    onPaste: function () {
        console.log('paste');
    },
    keyup: function () {
        console.log('keyup');
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? Why do you need to distinguish between `keyup` and `paste` rather than, for example, using an `input` event?

Comment: @skirtle oh, I didn't think about `input`. I will search that. thank you.

Comment: @skirtle there is old value in input element. I want to add new value. And can I know a new value what I pasted using `input` event?

Comment: If your question is "How to modify an input text after a user pasted some content?" that is another question please search SO for the answer which I am sure you will find. If not post this question and I am sure you will be answered hastily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us establish some fundamentals first so we can progress with your question:

**Establish HTML Native Events Fundamentals**

`onpaste` event is commonly triggered by users in either of these two ways:

1. User pressed `CTRL + V` buttons(`keydown` + `keyup` HTML events are fired for each button pressed
2. Right Mouse Click to open browser context menu and choose the option
   paste from it on the input (`contextmenu` HTML event is fired)

**Vue.js**

Vue.js has built in event listeners you can listen to for any native HTML events.
If you want to listen solely to the `onpaste` HTML event you simply need to listen just to this event with `@paste` as you did above.

**Unclear Motivation**

Trying to modify the browsers native behavior i.e that `paste` event would not be composed of the `keydown` / `keyup` / `contextmenu` events is simply impossible as long as you try to work with the browsers native HTML API. If you choose to build your own custom logic for pasting and prevent the default that is up to you but to be honest I truely do not understand what would be your motivation to do such a thing as the browser's native HTML events do exactly what they need to.

The main question I believe you need to be asking yourself is what you are trying to accomplish ? what is the Expected Behavior or challenge you are currently trying to solve. By clarifying this you may ask another question and get a more accurate answer that could help you progress with your current works. Good luck.